# How to fix docker error "no subsystem for mount"?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I pulled the **drools-workbench-showcase** image

```
docker pull jboss/drools-workbench-showcase
```

But if I try to run it in a docker container like it's proposed on the [drools-workbench-showcase](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/drools-workbench-showcase/) site:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -d --name drools-workbench jboss/drools-workbench-showcase:latest
```

I get an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: could not synchronise with container process: no subsystem for mount".
```

How can I fix it? (A couple of months ago I did the same and it worked without any additional efforts.) My OS is Ubuntu **18.04**

Answer (score 7):

So, what I've discovered in a meanwhile. It was an ubuntu-docker issue. Recently I upgraded my ubuntu from **16.04** to **18.04**. This change seems to be incompatible with the docker version I had, **1.11.0**. I followed the instructions from the site [How to Install and Use Docker on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04) and installed a new docker version, **18.06.1-ce** (above my old one). Now it works.
Reading the comment [Docker fails with "no subsystem for mount". Comment 29.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1411286#c29) helped me to come to this solution.